# Non-parametric proportion confidence interval with high N

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, references, proportion

Is there an equation for finding a confidence interval of the sample proportion from a nonparametric dataset? I can't seem to find anything that answers that question in a straight-forward way. (By the way, the N will be high&mdahs;in the 1000s—for this.)

If anyone could point me to any resources that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: What does "nonparametric dataset" mean? Do you just want a  95% CI for a proportion?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to use the CI to find an appropriate sample size such that the CI spans 1%, i.e. 99% proportion is between .95-.96. I want to assume as little as possible about the population I sample from so I want to use non-parametric statistics (if I can). Maybe I am overthinking and nonparametric stats aren't applied to proportion sampling/testing.

Comment: If your proportion is a number of events ('heads') out of a known number of trials ('coin flips'), the distribution *must be* Bernoulli. From there, we can find CI's various ways. Do you have actual data & need a CI, or do you have a theorized proportion & want to know the range of proportions you might reasonably expect to find in a future study?

Comment: I have actual data but not sure if I will find the CI the right way. I am sampling from a dataset where rows are actions, but I am sampling by _person_. I then want to find the confidence interval of the sample proportion for people who did action X (vs not). Taking it a step further, I want to find a second confidence interval for people who did action Y after action X.

Comment: You could look at "Bollinger Bands" - but it might be more heuristic than statistic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollinger_Bands

Comment: Thanks: followup question: I sample a population, each n has x attributes with values 0 or 1. These attributes are funnel/path-like & I want to compute a proportion confidence interval for each attribute. For attribute 1 I want to find CI for successes/failures (0 or 1). For attribute 2 I want to find CI for success/failure based on if attribute 1 was a success (as they continue on a path). I want the CI for people who have (1,0 or 1,1) - then for attribute 3 I want to find (1,1,0 or 1,1,1) - Can I use the proportions of n with these traits in the sample for the CI or is there more complexity?